# QGIS clipping OpenStreetMap but still being able to run functions such as ORS Tools on the layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins, route, qgis-network-analysis

I have struggled to find a solution to be able to clip an OpenStreetMap (OSM) raster layer but still run functions using plugins such as ORS Tools. I would like to clip OSM with an overlaying vector layer, but not for aesthetic purposes. I have seen solutions where you convert the OSM raster layer into an image, but this would get rid of information contained in the original layer.

With my clipped OSM layer I would like to be able to run a route analysis / network analysis of the roads in my study area. The reason for clipping the OSM is because there are certain stretches of roads that I want the plugins to avoid when calculating the shortest route.

Plugins for QGIS such as ORS Tools and TravelTime allow network analysis but I believe they do this (please correct me if I am wrong) by using road and route data through their own databases.

Is there a way I can clip an OSM layer (or something similar) in QGIS and then be able to calculate the shortest route between two points using only the roads on this newly clipped layer?

If you know of a solution for Esri I would be happy to give that a go too.

Comment: Please don't create a new account to repost a closed question - it isn't fooling anyone. Go back and fix the first question with your new information and it will be considered for reopening,

Comment: I got told to "get use to the Asking/Answering model", so I read all the links people sent me and tried to improve my question. Now with this question, I have asked about a different issue trying my best to structure it correctly. I am trying to gain experience in how to use the site properly and build upon feedback that people give me, by asking for help with issues like the one above.

Comment: You have one question - that this might be a different approach to but it is the same question. Please remember that we (the moderators) are volunteers and so can not be expected to spend a lot of time determining if someone who hasn't taken the [tour] yet is genuinely asking a *slightly* different question or simply gaming the system with his other account. Please take the time to get to know this community, hang out, answer some questions gain our trust and see if you can develop into a useful member. Until then please stop moaning and fix your behaviour.

Comment: Any closed question will be considered for reopening after you have made an edit to it - if the edit is in good faith and improves the question the community (or the moderators) can vote to reopen it.

Comment: I am very confused at your interpretation of this. It is not the same question at all, but I guess that is for you to decide. I appreciate you volunteer to help this community, but you took the time to make the bold accusation that I was trying to "fool" people on here. Surely you understand my frustration when I can not even go back and edit the previous question.

Comment: I can't help it if you managed to create two accounts with the same name - only a Stackexchange Admins can fix that - https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts. Fornow I would concentrate on making this question sufficiently different that it is not a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help. I shall completely rewrite this question so that the answers have no relevance to the problem I face :) Enjoy your coffee